# aget returns a java object when applied to a `make-array` array

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I expect the following code to return the (0,0) value. Yet I get a java object

```
(let [axs (make-array Long 5 5 0)]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  (aget axs 0 0))
```

Also I got  a type mismatch when trying to mutate index (0,0)

```
(let [axs (make-array Long 5 5 0)]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  (aset axs 0 0 1))
```

I expect to have initialized a Long[5][5] java array to zero. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: First your array is not initialized, second if you want a 2D array you have to remove the 0 at the end of your make-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Third argument to `make-array` doesn't initialize your array with zeros, but adds third array dimension, which size is equal to zero. As a result, the size of your array is zero as well. To fix the issue, create your array as follows:

```
(make-array Long/TYPE 5 5)
```

This will create array of *primitive longs* and will initialize it with zeros.

Comment: `Long/TYPE` is the class literal representing primitive longs (as opposed to `java.lang.Long` indicating the wrapper class, or box)  so `(make-array Long/TYPE 5 5)` *does* create a 2d array of primitive longs.

Comment: @sw1nn that's correct! I was sure that `(type (make-array Long/TYPE 5 5))` returned `[[Ljava.lang.Long;` for me in the REPL, but, indeed, it returns `[[J`. Probably, I had messed something up. I've reverted the answer to it's initial version